# Does Asus H87M-E better fit with 2x8GB or 4x4GB RAM combination?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am planning to buy asus H87M-E motherboard (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H87ME/). I read that some motherboards are better suited for 2 modules, and some better for 4.

So does 2x8GB or 4x4GB combination better fit to this motherboard?

If 2-module combination is better for this motherboard, should I put them into yellow or grey slots (image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motherbaord supports up to 32GB (4 * 8GB), so you should take the 2 8GB modules to have the possibility to upgrade later the RAM to the mentioned 32GB.

Comment: This is precisely the same reasoning I had when I built my system - I'd add for 'which slots', I'd consult the manual, since those things arn't standardised